# How to add a password to an existing private key in Java

Tags: java, security, encryption, openssl, rsa

Say I have a previously created private key using openssl, but I've decided not to protect it with a passphrase:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
BASE64 ENCODED DATA
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

But then I realised that I want to protect it.

I know how to protect it using openssl, but I have a requirement to do it in Java. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First load and extract the pkcs#1 unencrypted key from the pem file

```
String pem = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("rsa.key")));
String privateKeyPEM = pem.replace(
        "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n", "")
             .replace("-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
 byte[] encodedPrivateKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(privateKeyPEM);
```

And then encrypt the key using the second part of [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6164414/6371459)  ( I have included It)

```
 // We must use a PasswordBasedEncryption algorithm in order to encrypt the private key, you may use any common algorithm supported by openssl, you can check them in the openssl documentation http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkcs8.html
String MYPBEALG = "PBEWithSHA1AndDESede";
String password = "pleaseChangeit!";

int count = 20;// hash iteration count
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
byte[] salt = new byte[8];
random.nextBytes(salt);

// Create PBE parameter set
PBEParameterSpec pbeParamSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, count);
PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray());
SecretKeyFactory keyFac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(MYPBEALG);
SecretKey pbeKey = keyFac.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);

Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance(MYPBEALG);

// Initialize PBE Cipher with key and parameters
pbeCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, pbeParamSpec);

// Encrypt the encoded Private Key with the PBE key
byte[] ciphertext = pbeCipher.doFinal(encodedPrivateKey);

// Now construct  PKCS #8 EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo object
AlgorithmParameters algparms = AlgorithmParameters.getInstance(MYPBEALG);
algparms.init(pbeParamSpec);
EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo encinfo = new EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo(algparms, ciphertext);

// and here we have it! a DER encoded PKCS#8 encrypted key!
byte[] encryptedPkcs8 = encinfo.getEncoded();
```

Use the following code to decrypt (extrscted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34386901/java-write-and-read-password-based-encrypted-private-key))

```
public static PrivateKey getPrivateKey(byte[]   encryptedPkcs8, String passwd) throws Exception{

        EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo encryptPKInfo = new EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo(encryptedPkcs8);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(encryptPKInfo.getAlgName());
        PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passwd.toCharArray());
        SecretKeyFactory secFac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(encryptPKInfo.getAlgName());
        Key pbeKey = secFac.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
        AlgorithmParameters algParams = encryptPKInfo.getAlgParameters();
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, algParams);
        KeySpec pkcs8KeySpec = encryptPKInfo.getKeySpec(cipher);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        return kf.generatePrivate(pkcs8KeySpec);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but does a -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- header refer to a pkcs8 or a pkcs1 format ?

Comment: how do you decrypt you privateKey back ?

Comment: @EvgeniyMishutin I have added an example to decode the pkcs8 encrypted key

Comment: @pedrofb, I'll try it now and accept the answer if it works.

Comment: I want to decrypt the key using openssl, so can you please tell me how to  add the rsa header to encrypted key ?

Comment: @VikramSinghShekhawat,  openssl can decrypt private keys in PKCS#1 and PKCS#8 format. If you have a Java-generated key (PKCS # 8) you can use the `openssl pkcs8` command providing the binary data (DER) or PEM format. See http://openssl.cs.utah.edu/docs/apps/pkcs8.html